# JSF-page's memory usage increases fast with usage - massive amounts of CSSStyleRules and CSSStyleSheets - Why?

Tags: jsf, memory-leaks

I have a JSF page that I'm developing, and many users are experiencing problems with memory leaks and slow performance after using the page for a couple of minutes. The page is a webshop and when the user searches for an item, tables of items are then generated. I've checked the memory usage using devtools in Chrome, taking a snapshot before and after certain operations. Along with obvious  memory leaks, like the detached DOM-objects, there are also a ton of CSSStyleRules and CSSStyleSheets taking up a lot of memory.

Here is an image of the memory usage before using the page: [image]

Here is an image of the memory usage after using the page for a while: [image]

My question is: What is normally the cause of these types of memory issues with styling? Any common culprits? How can I proceed to find where these come from?

I'm running Primefaces 6.0, Omnifaces 2.6.1 and JSF 2.2

Any tips are much appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: it souns like you aren't removing things from your DOM when you draw new items a generated you are not properly disposing of the old items. Just a guess

Comment: `CSSStyleRules` do not come from PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Melloware Yeah this is my guess too, however I'm not sure how to find out where this happens, and what I can do about it. Most of my code is either pure backend Java, and the frontend is mostly just xhtml with occasional basic JavaScript. My impression is that only the JavaScript code can be the cause of these types of leaks, or is that incorrect? Could it be that the backend logic somehow causes these issues too?

Comment: See Jasper's comment CSSStyleRules is definitely not coming from PrimeFaces. you should find out where it comes from and work backwards from there.

Comment: @Melloware Alright. Do you have any idea how to locate where these come from? When I check the memory snapshots in devtools I cannot get any information of their whereabouts. Is the only way to simply remove the styling one-by-one and see when this problem disappears? Any tips on how to proceed?